# Package to Analyse Eye Tracking data

Tags: r, eye-tracking

I'm doing a research on saccadic eye movements for pre-dementia.

There's a package for Saccade and Fixation Detection from eye tracking data

https://github.com/tmalsburg/saccades

How can I get the eye tracking data?

Comment: There's a short intro in the github of the package. Is that insufficient for your needs?

Comment: I dont know how can i get eye tracking data

Comment: @sarmad? Do you just need the data?

Comment: yes that is my question

Comment: yes , I don't have an idea about how to get the data